# A meromorphic function $f$ with poles of order $2$ at $\sqrt { n }$ ($n=1,2,3,...$),

Tags: complex-analysis

find a meromorphic function $f$
with poles of order 2 at $\sqrt { n }$
($n=1,2,3,...$), the Residue at each
pole is $2$ , and $\lim _ { z \rightarrow \sqrt { n } } ( z - \sqrt { n } ) ^ { 2 } f ( z ) = 1$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

I tried with $f ( z ) = \frac { 1 } { \left( \sin \pi z^ { 2 } \right) ^ { 2 } }$
, but conditions are not fully
conciding

Comment: Yep there will be issues, because it will have zeroes at every negative integer too. But it is a good start.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem